# What kind of font is used in this logo_

Tags: css, fonts, styling

I am not sure if this question is fit for SO but if anybody could help me that would be fine.
http://www.mdvstyle.com/wp-content/themes/mdv-child/img/logo.png

It doesn't have to be the exact same font, but something similar.

Comment: It fits http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/ better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you google for Font determiner.

It gives you results where you can upload the picture to find the font (or closest to) like on this page: https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/